# Variable fetching as null in Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, null

[image]

[image]

Hi all
Iam facing an issue in the Linux shell script, TFN is fetching as NULL.
Can someone help regarding the issue will be helpful

Comment: Aren't you redirecting the query to a logfile ?

Comment: Just fetching the value from query to TFN and doing doing echo for TFN. There is no error in the logfile, shell script is running fine

Comment: `sqlplus ... << EOF >Log` - doesn't that send all the output to the log file ? So TFN will be empty.

Comment: Thanks @John3136 it worked out, removed the logfile and now TFN value is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TFN=`sqlplus -s $LOGNAME1/$PASSWORD1@connstr << EOF > ${LogFileName}
...
EOF`
```

Is redirecting the sqlplus output to your logfile and the command had no output (it's gone to the log file) so TFN is empty.

Remove the `> ${LogFileName}` to TFN gets the value of the query and then `echo $FN >> ${LogFileName}` if you really want the query results in the log.